# How do I clear the utc value from a luxon datetime?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, luxon

I have a luxon DateTime that looks something like this:

```
this.eventParams.date.toString()
=> '2023-02-23T00:00:00.000-08:00'
```

It includes the utc offset of -08:00

How do I clear this value in Luxon so that it's 0?

Problem - When I pass this to my controller, C# converts this utc offset to a TimeOfDay in my controller.

```
// .Net Controller
eventParams.Date
=> {02/23/2023 08:00:00}
```

where eventParams.Date is a

```
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `DateTime` instance whose time zone is set to UTC using [`DateTime.toUTC(offset, opts)`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoutc)

Example:

```html
<script type="module">

import * as luxon from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.2.1/build/es6/luxon.js";

const dtLocal = luxon.DateTime.now();
const dtUtc = dtLocal.toUTC();

console.log("local:", dtLocal.toString());
console.log("utc:", dtUtc.toString());

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really mean by this question is "how do I get a specific date in UTC instead of a local time?" Because what's happening is that you're creating "day at midnight" as a local datetime, then sending it to a server that works in UTC, which will convert it, thus adding 8 hours. So instead of this:

```js
const myDate = DateTime.local(2023, 2, 23);
```

you want:

```
const myDate = DateTime.utc(2023, 2, 23);
```

Note that of course will be a local time of 14:00 the previous day! Which is fine because that's what you want.